# Is it possible to have creator and updater separately in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my `Store` model, I have `author` attribute so I can tack who wrote and updated a store. However, I would like to have who created and who updated separately. I think I have to get who created in my `save_model` in `admin.py`.

Is there a way to get a creator and updater separately in Django admin?

**models.py**

```
class Store(models.Model):
    ...
    author = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, editable=False,
                        related_name='promotions_of_author', null=True, blank=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
class StoreAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    ...
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if getattr(obj, 'author', None) is None:
            obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have two separate fields in the model to keep track of who updated it and created it ?

I usually keep two fields to keep track of this.In that case you may have something like this :

```
    class StoreAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):

        def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
            # adding the entry for the first time
            if not change:
                obj.created_by = request.user

            # updating already existing record
            else:
                obj.updated_by = request.user

            obj.save()
```

Comment: Works very well! Thanks